# Не получается отправить форму через ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть такой код:

```js
$('#form').submit(e => {
 e.preventDefault();
  
  $.post(e.target.action, new FormData(e.target), result => {
   console.log(result);
  }, e.target.enctype);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" action="https://example.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="document.getElementById('form').submit()" />
</form>
```

То есть есть файловый инпут на форме. Надо чтобы форма отправлялась при выборе файла (сделал в событии `onchange`). Но отправить надо ajax-запросом (чтобы страница не перезагружалась). Не получается... В событие `submit` почему-то не заходит вообще.

Еще пытался вот так:

```
$('#importExcelFileInput').change(e => {
    const form = document.getElementById('importExcelForm');

    $.post(form.action, new FormData(form), result => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Но тогда при запросе выкидывает ошибку `jquery.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`. Вообще не понимаю что это значит...

Answer (score 3):

У вас две ошибки:

1. `document.getElementById('form').submit()` - не вызывает событие `onsubmit`. Если вы используете `jquery` - можно воспользоваться функцией `trigger`.
2. Не правильно отправляете файл. Отправка через `post` функцию в **jquery** предпологает отправку `JSON`, он пытается сконвертировать файл в `JSON`, поэтому ошибка `Illegal invocation`.

Посмотрите работающий пример.

```js
$('#form').submit(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  $.ajax({
    url: e.target.action,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('error');
    },
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<form id="form" action="https://example.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="$('#form').trigger('submit')" />
</form>
```